# How to make python scripts to wait for linux script to be completed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am preparing python script which will control other python and linux scripts in correct sequence. And I have one doubt about below code:

```
import os
import unittest

class TestDict(unittest.TestCase):

    x = factory.FileGenerator()
    os.system('./linux_script.sh')

    def test_dict(self):
        self.assertDictEqual(self.test, self.json, 'Message')
```

As you can see at first I am preparing files and then run `linux_script.sh`. Next step is to compare two dict, but it cannot be done until linux script will be completed - the script is running other application which creates .json file. Until .json file is not prepared, test_dict cannot be executed because it will fail.

Question: python will be waiting for this line to be completed: `os.system('./linux_script.sh`, and then run test? If not how I can force python to do that?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Comment: Using a relative path for a script is inviting trouble in the future.  Better to put the script in a well-known directory and add that to your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system()` does wait for the command to complete before returning.

Note that, since you're calling the function directly inside the class body, this will execute when your test class *is being loaded*, not when it gets instantiated. If that's not what you want, move the call into the constructor, a set up method or directly into the test method itself.

Comment: I will add it to a setUp method. Thanks